# How to write a Python wrapper for print()?

Tags: c, python-2.7

I have a little experience working with Python C Binding wrappers but the function that's giving me the most grief right now is a print(). For example, in the C header file the function looks like

```
void NumPrint(void* self, FILE* stream)
```

and that function **prints a description of an object instance to a stream.** It takes two parameters, the first being a reference to a number object that should be printed, the second being a stream to which the description should be printed

I am unsure about how to approach the wrapper for this. Here's an example of a simple wrapper that wraps add() which adds two numbers together...

```
static PyObject *wrapper(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    // return a C double representation
    double inX = PyFloat_AsDouble(args);

    // PyObject to return
    PyObject* ret;

    // run function
    double out = c_add(inX, inX);

    // build result into PyFloatObject**strong text**
    ret = PyFloat_FromDouble(out);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: from the page https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers it says you can update your question with the research you made since you posted it first. don't lose hope, surely someone knowledgeable will come and read your question

Comment: thank you @bobrobob. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and still understanding it.

Comment: to be strict, print() is not global function (like seems in high-level), but method in Python object. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html

Comment: ... and print() as I understand can be "wrapped" by pure python code https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer...

```
static PyObject* NumberPrintWrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* reference){

    FILE* out = NULL;
    size_t size;

    // create buffer
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(*buffer));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        handle_error("buffer");
    }

    // map buffer to stream using open_memstream()
    out = open_memstream(&buffer, &size);
    if (out == NULL)
    {
        handle_error("open_memstream");
    }

    // call function that requires stream
    long* s = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(reference);
    NumPrint(s, out);

    // close file handle
    fclose(out);

    // hand over to Python
    PyObject* string = PyString_FromString(buffer);

    free(buffer);

    return string;
}
```